# Let $a$ be the real root of the equation $x^3+x+1=0$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $a$ be the real root of the equation $x^3+x+1=0$

Calculate $$\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{{(3a^{2}-2a+2)(3a^{2}+2a)}}+a^{2}$$

The correct answer should be $ 1 $. I've tried to write $a^3$ as $-a-1$ but that didn't too much, I guess there is some trick here :s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there is a trick to it, but good ol' factoring can work here.

It is easy to check (using the identity $a^3=-a-1$) that
$$ (3a^2-2a+2)(3a^2+2a) = -5a-7a^2 $$
Let $\sqrt[3]{-5a-7a^2}+a^2 = y$. Given that $a\in \mathbb{R}$, we know that also $y\in \mathbb{R}$, and we must solve for it.
$$y-a^2 = \sqrt[3]{-5a-7a^2} \\ (y-a^2)^3 = -5a-7a^2 \\ y^3 - 3y^2a^2 + 3ya^4-a^6 = -5a-7a^2 \\ y^3-3y^2a^2+3ya(-a-1)-(-a-1)^2=-5a-7a^2 \\ y^3-3y^2a^2-3ya^2-3ya+6a^2+3a-1=0$$ So many threes, only the $6$ stands out. But if we use $6=3+3$: $$ (y^3-1)+(3a^2-3y^2a^2)+(3a^2+3a-3ya^2-3ya)=0 \\ (y^3-1)-3a^2(y^2-1)-(3a^2+3a)(y-1)=0$$ As one can see, it is possible to factor out $(y-1)$, thereby concluding that $y=1$ is a solution.

Comment: Simple and clean, thank you ^^

Comment: @DavidQuinn all other solutions to the final equation are complex. You can see this because we defined $y = \sqrt[3]{-5a-7a^2}+a^2$, where $\sqrt[3]{.}$ denoted the real cube root, and there is only one real cube root of a real number.

Answer (score 3):

The expansion of what is under square root gives

$$A=9a^4+6a^3-6a^3-4a^2+6a^2+4a=$$
$$a (9a^3+2a+4)=a (9 (-a-1)+2a+4)=$$
$$-a (7a+5)=$$

this must be equal to
$$B=(1-a^2)^3=1-3a^2+3a^4-a^6=$$
$$$$

the difference is
$$B-A=1+4a^2+5a+3a^4-(a+1)^2=$$
$$3a^2+3a+3a^4=3a (a^3+a+1)=0$$

It is correct.

Comment: Well, it is easy that way, when you know a solution. What about without knowing it ?

Comment: @ChristianF: without knowing it, given the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ one may compute the minimal polynomial of $Q(\alpha)$ with $Q$ being any algebraic function. It is time-consuming but it leads to the same outcome, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The real root $a$ of $x^3+x+1$ belongs to the interval $\left(-1,-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and in order to check that
$$ \sqrt[3]{(3a^2-2a+2)(3a^2+2a)}=1-a^2 \tag{1}$$
holds it is enough to check that
$$ (3a^2-2a+2)(3a^2+2a)=1-3a^2+3a^4+a^6 \tag{2}$$
holds, or that 
$$  (1+a+a^3)(-1+5a+a^3) = 0 \tag{3} $$
holds, but that is trivial.

Comment: Can you calculate without knowing it is $1$ in advance?

Comment: @vadim123: I have just replied about it to ChristianF, I am going to paste the comment above: without knowing it, given the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ one may compute the minimal polynomial of $Q(\alpha)$ with $Q$ being any algebraic function. It is time-consuming but it leads to the same outcome, of course.

Comment: An alternative approach is to perform some trigonometry, since the polynomial $x^3+x+1$ is related to $\cos\frac{2\pi}{9}$ and $a$ has a not-so-simple-but-still-manageable trigonometric form.

Comment: Please explain the downvote, I will be happy to improve the answer.

Comment: Downvote wasn't me; I gave +1.

Answer (score 1):

The expression under the cube root is $$9a^4+2a^2+4a=9a(-(a+1))+2a^2+4a=-7a^2-5a$$

Meanwhile consider $$(1-a^2)^3=1-3a^2+3a^4-a^6=1-3a^2+3a(-a-1)-a^2-2a-1$$
$$=-7a^2-5a$$

So the required result follows immediately

Comment: Can you calculate without knowing it is $1$ in advance?